# Changing CSS with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

When using JavaScript to change the CSS does the JavaScript simply make new inline-CSS which takes presidents? I've always felt inline CSS is trashy and was wondering if there's a better way?

For example if you have

`<div id="author">Author's name</div>` which is normally coloured green from a reference to an external CSS and you want to change it to red must you use

```
document.getElementById('author').style.color='#FF0000'
```

Must changes to appearance be done using inline-stying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not modifiying the CSS. You're just setting `style` properties. The mark up of an element is decided by three things: CSS, `style` and inline properties like `width="100"`. The order in which they are applied can get a little fuzzy.

`style` does always overrule CSS though, unless you're using `!important`.

A more common way to change the mark up of elements is to add and remove classes. This allows you to keep all your style definitions in your CSS file and makes your code considerably less complex.

You could do:

```
document.getElementById('author').className = "selected";
```

to add a class to it and have it be display in a different mark up.

If you're using jQuery you can use `addClass` and `removeClass`. Under the hood this just modifies the `className` property. It's easy enough to write your own implementation, you just need to do some string juggling.

Comment: That last paragraph is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Celeritas - also ask yourself *why* it's green and *why* it changes to red, and pick your class names based on those reasons (class="green" is a travesty!) ... you could have `id="author" class="selected"` and rule that says `#author.selected { color:#FF0000; }`

Comment: @StephenP that is indeed really good advice. Name your classes after the thing they indicate; not the effect they give. If you change your color palette at some point the class names might look silly and that's bad for understanding and general code quality.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to change the styling of an HTML element. If using jQuery, for instance, you can add/remove class names to elements easily, like so:

```
$("div").addClass("className");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always cleaner to define all your styles in classes so you can change the whole application look and feel easily instead of using inline styles.

the easiest way to do so is to define a CSS class

```
.reddiv {color: #FF0000}
```

then you can easily change the color of the div to red using jquery

```
$('#author').addClass('reddiv');
```